# Problems of reading and writing files when using Visual Studio to run C++ programs

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

Recently I'm tring to use Visual Studio to write c++ programs. However, I don't know where to put the input and output files which the program will read. I tried to put the input and output files in the directory ''...\Projects\ConsoleApplication\ConsoleApplication'', which is the same directory with ConsoleApplication.vcxproj file. This works well when I press the start debugging button(F5). However, when I press the start without debugging button(ctrl+F5). The program can't read and write to the files. Can anyone explain what happended?

Answer (score 0):

Generally the files needs to be in the working project environment.  Right click on the sidebar and add them to the project.  The root directory will work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give your file path in your programs,

```
ofstream f1("d:\\me.txt");
```